# Autoit - Function Returns Array , add it to another array

Tags: arrays, error-handling, autoit

```
#include <ImageSearch.au3>
#include <Array.au3>
$x1=0
$y1=0
Global $aArray_Base3[64]
Dim $foo = TimeToPlay()

Func _XX()
$RET = _ArrayAdd($aArray_Base3, $foo[0])
sleep(250)
$RE1T = _ArrayAdd($aArray_Base3, $foo[1])
_ArrayDisplay($aArray_Base3, "AKA")
EndFunc

Func _XXX()
$result = _ImageSearchArea("AK.png",1,664, 320,692, 357,$x1,$y1,0)
    Local $aArray_Base2[0]
if $result=1 Then
   $result = "AK"
   _ArrayAdd($aArray_Base2, $result)
EndIf
$result2 = _ImageSearchArea("AS.png",1,664, 320,692, 357,$x1,$y1,0)
if $result2=1 Then
   $result2 = "AS"
   _ArrayAdd($aArray_Base2, $result2)
EndIf
Return $aArray_Base2
EndFunc
```

> ERROR : ==> Array variable has incorrect number of subscripts or subscript dimension range exceeded.:
>   $RET = _ArrayAdd($aArray_Base3, $foo[0])                                                              $RET = _ArrayAdd($aArray_Base3, ^ ERROR

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by adding this :

```
Func TimeToPlay2()

Global $foo = TimeToPlay()
$RET = _ArrayAdd($aArray_Base3, $foo[0])
sleep(250)
$RE1T = _ArrayAdd($aArray_Base3, $foo[1])
_ArrayDisplay($aArray_Base3, "1D - Delim string")

EndFunc
```